# How to use strings from php array in postgresql query?

Tags: php, postgresql

need help with using php variables in postgresql query.
I am trying to make several queries to postgresql database using php array elements, but it does't work. Can anybody help?

```
// $nums array with strings like - "983458999893440"  

for ($i=0; $i<count($nums); $i++){  

 $tm = pg_escape_string($nums[$i]);  

 $sql = "SELECT SUM(sp.summ) FROM tk.sp_tran sp WHERE sp.long_pan ='{$tm}'";  

   $panSum = dbCon::conn($sql);//return result of pg_fetch_all();  

//Code above don't work  
//Code below is ok   

 $tm = pg_escape_string("983458999893440");  

 $sql = "SELECT SUM(sp.summ) FROM tk.sp_tran sp WHERE sp.long_pan ='{$tm}'";  

   $panSum = dbCon::conn($sql);//return result of pg_fetch_all();  

//Please help to understand what is wrong?
```

Comment: Please format and paste complete code. Also let us know what the actual problem/error is.

Comment: it's doesn't made what you wan't or you have an error message ? If you have error message paste it too thanks !

Comment: It returns null in first case, not error

Comment: Result of print_r  -  "Array ( [0] => Array ( [sum] => ) ) 1" in case with array string element  
Result of print_r - " Array ( [0] => Array ( [sum] => 27000 ) ) 1" in case with string

Comment: I use the same string in both cases

Comment: print $tm and maybe $nums[$i], then check if it actually is the same string in that array element

Comment: I used strcoll on $tm and $nums[$i], it showed difference ((( ,
I got $nums[] from csv table, Any ideas what is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I find a space symbol before first letter of the string in csv file. So code is ok. It is just my an inattention(((